# Which nodes a hadoop file is stored on

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to find which datanodes a particular hdfs file is stored on, or a list of blocks that store an hdfs file?

For example, if I have hdfs://user/person/file.csv,

Is there a way to find a list of ext4 paths corresponding to the blocks that make up this file on the datanodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can find out the location of blocks which are stored on different datanodes in HDFS. Here is the command:

```
hdfs fsck /user/hduser/file.txt -files -blocks -locations
```

This will give you all the information related to individual blocks created for file: "/user/hduser/file.txt". Output generally looks like this:

```
[hduser@node001 ~]$ hdfs fsck /user/hduser/file.txt -files -blocks -locations
Connecting to namenode via http://node001.morado.com:50070
FSCK started by hduser (auth:SIMPLE) from /192.168.2.169 for path /user/hduser/file.txt at Mon Jul 11 23:14:27 PDT 2016
/user/hduser/file.txt 1073839694 bytes, 9 block(s):  OK
0. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847742_7107323 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-25d2b73a-2dc2-48c1-9aad-f0f5ca8d302a,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.147:50010,DS-293a7f8d-ad31-4bc1-98d8-0c0822eda305,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.20:50010,DS-8efb7a6e-08f0-4f2d-aee2-bc5a102277bd,DISK]]
1. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847748_7107329 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-6881b609-1473-48d5-a07c-f111e0bdcf2f,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.15:50010,DS-060c75ff-5632-4f6f-a73b-fb2a68927c63,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.147:50010,DS-3e108776-d3bd-4b84-b68a-59e1ca755331,DISK]]
2. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847753_7107334 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-25d2b73a-2dc2-48c1-9aad-f0f5ca8d302a,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.177:50010,DS-b7a33931-8917-4fe2-b2ec-2e4c3d5b6b01,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.135:50010,DS-5efb0813-7e4e-4d27-8fa4-7f8f3b2e6e3c,DISK]]
3. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847760_7107341 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-6881b609-1473-48d5-a07c-f111e0bdcf2f,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.20:50010,DS-b8a5ceaf-6953-4842-8930-29b286ccb7cf,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.134:50010,DS-c6418fbb-6e30-447e-b507-bf19e0f28fd1,DISK]]
4. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847764_7107345 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-95636645-c59e-4bca-8478-c15b3c16d514,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.147:50010,DS-293a7f8d-ad31-4bc1-98d8-0c0822eda305,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.20:50010,DS-8efb7a6e-08f0-4f2d-aee2-bc5a102277bd,DISK]]
5. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847768_7107349 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-6881b609-1473-48d5-a07c-f111e0bdcf2f,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.20:50010,DS-276bd2c8-ee3d-4cd3-b655-17a83917c45b,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.134:50010,DS-5e128658-c876-46df-b10e-5962baf73db2,DISK]]
6. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847772_7107353 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-fa57d5e9-a187-4856-8bf2-6933e63b3afe,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.135:50010,DS-f5f1e2a0-186b-4c70-844f-7e7ebe389f50,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.15:50010,DS-8cfb8ffb-77b6-40bb-930e-81c7198166ad,DISK]]
7. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847776_7107357 len=134217728 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-95636645-c59e-4bca-8478-c15b3c16d514,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.15:50010,DS-060c75ff-5632-4f6f-a73b-fb2a68927c63,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.147:50010,DS-3e108776-d3bd-4b84-b68a-59e1ca755331,DISK]]
8. BP-778802867-192.168.2.147-1465886958278:blk_1080847780_7107361 len=97870 repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.169:50010,DS-25d2b73a-2dc2-48c1-9aad-f0f5ca8d302a,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.15:50010,DS-de3cffa6-cef4-4f47-9bbf-5f44214b3a5a,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.2.177:50010,DS-847ec520-bc14-4ca4-af94-21140a3b20f6,DISK]]

Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    1073839694 B
 Total dirs:    0
 Total files:   1
 Total symlinks:        0
 Total blocks (validated):  9 (avg. block size 119315521 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   9 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:    0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:   0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:     0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication: 3.0
 Corrupt blocks:        0
 Missing replicas:      0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:      7
 Number of racks:       1
FSCK ended at Mon Jul 11 23:14:27 PDT 2016 in 1 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/user/hduser/file.txt' is HEALTHY
```

Look for the information after "repl", usually starting with "DatanodeInfoWithStorage" tag. It gives the required information about datanode locations.